# How to call getStaticProps again?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

I'm building a language picker in my Next.js app. When I change the language, I want Next to refetch the data with that locale. How could I do that?

I'm fetching my data in GetStaticProps and I somehow need to get the new locale there and refetch the data with said locale.

Comment: Pages that use `getStaticProps` will get pre-rendered at build time for each locale your Next.js app supports. Simply routing to the localized path when changing the language (with `next/router` or `next/link`) should be enough.

Answer (score 1):

The `context` argument inside the [nextjs](/questions/tagged/nextjs) `getStaticProps` function already contains a [`locale`](https://nextjs.org/docs/advanced-features/i18n-routing#locale-strategies) parameter, which can be used to alter your query.

For example it could look something like:

```js
export async function getStaticProps({ locale }) {
   if (locale === 'en') {
      const props = await fetch(<some 'en' specific fetch>)
      return { props }
   } else {
      const props = await fetch(<some default fetch>)
      return { props }
   }
}
```

> As a small optimalizaion caviat, the `locale` change causes props to be fetched even if there is no content to be applied. You can prevent this from happening by providing the `notFound` property in the returned object.
>
> ```js
> export async function getStaticProps({ locale }) {
>   const res = await fetch(`https://some-fetchDB/${locale}`)
>   const blogPosts = await res.json() 
>   if (blogPosts.length === 0) {
>      return {
>        notFound: true
>      }
>   }
>
> }
> ```

The getStaticProps method does refresh automatically based on the [react rehydration](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-dom.html#hydrate) and will update on every locale change automatically (if deemed necessary).

You can read up on static optimalization and hydration in [nextjs](/questions/tagged/nextjs) [here](https://nextjs.org/docs/advanced-features/automatic-static-optimization).

---

In case you're not using the native [nextjs](/questions/tagged/nextjs) locale solution to store the current locale, then your general solution would most likely entail enclosing the entire page component in a context provider and performing a fetch (in `useEffect`). But it's hard to be specific without you providing more details in the question.

> *Last but not least I'd like to mention it seems rather strange that you would want to perform a fetch based on user's locale (as it sounds like incorrectly stored data - in terms of DB architecture, that should not be saved in DB). There are solutions like [linguijs](https://lingui.js.org/) which most likely cover your localization use-cases without the need of storing any of that data in the database*